# Problem removing leading zeros using a list comprehension best expression

Tags: python

`result` is a list of numbers:

```
result = ['0','5','0','1']
```

I want to remove the leading zero, using the following expression:

```
result = result[next((i for i, x in enumerate(result)
                if x != 0), len(result)):] or [0]
```

My problem is two-fold:

1.) I don't understand the expression as it is
2.) The expression as it is doesn't work: it doesn't remove any zeros  (leading or otherwise)

I'd expect the list comprehension to remove every zero, not just the leading ones.
I'm also confused at to what the len(result)): part of the expression is doing?

Comment: The second argument to `next` is the default when the iterable is exhausted. From the looks of it, this is supposed to be finding the index of the first 0, if it exists, and slicing the list accordingly.

Comment: This doesn't work because your items are strings and the condition checks against and integer. Change it to `result[next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != '0'), len(result)):] or ['0']` and it should work.

Comment: Where did you find this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you've used!

```
>>> result = ['0','5','0','1']
>>> result[next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0), len(result)):] or [0]
['0', '5', '0', '1']
```

Lets **break down** your list comprehension!

`[i for i,x in enumarate(result)]` unpacks the `enumerate(result)` as i and x. That is,

```
>>> enumerate(result)
<enumerate object at 0x7fc81d12bdc0>
>>> list(enumerate(result))
[(0, '0'), (1, '5'), (2, '0'), (3, '1')]
>>> for i,x in enumerate(result):
...     print i,x
...
0 0
1 5
2 0
3 1
```

**Filtering the results with non zero values,**

```
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Now see the difference in comparing a string and an integer with `x`

```
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != '0'] #list comprehension 
[1, 3]

>>> len(result)
4
```

> next(iterator[, default])
>
> **Return the next item from the iterator**. If default is given and the iterator
>      is exhausted, it is returned instead of raising StopIteration.

That is,

```
>>> next([i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0], len(result)) # next takes first argument as iterator, in this example we've given a list, so exception is raised
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list object is not an iterator
>>> next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != '0'), len(result)) #comparing with string '0' 
1
```

Now, we've got the first index of the list that has non zero values(lets have it as  nzindex).

With that index, we do [string slicing](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings) to get all the elements after the result[nzindex:]

This will return all elements after the index till the end.

```
>>> result[next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != '0'), len(result)):]
['5', '0', '1']
```

If the string slicing returns an empty list(falsey result), the default value result[0] is returned!

```
>>> result = ['0']
>>> result[next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != '0'), len(result)):] or result[0]
['0']
```

With that said if you want to **remove all the zeros in the list**,

```
>>> result = ['0','5','0','1']
>>> [x for i,x in enumerate(result) if x!='0']
['5', '1']
```

and if you want to **remove only the leading zeros**, a more efficient way would be,

```
>>> next(i for i,x in enumerate(result) if x!='0')
1
>>> result[next(i for i,x in enumerate(result) if x!='0'):]
['5', '0', '1']
```

Answer (score 3):

The expression looks for the first non-zero in the list, returning the remaining list.  More detail at the bottom.

**ANALYSIS**

However, you have characters: there is no integer `0` in your list.  Therefore, the expression merely returns the original list.

**SOLUTION**

If you want it to work on characters, simply include the quotation marks required:

```
result[next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != '0'), len(result)):] or ['0']
```

This give you:

Original code:

```
>>> result = ['0','5','0','1']
>>> result[next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != 0), len(result)):] or [0]
['0', '5', '0', '1']
```

Adapted to strings / characters:

```
>>> result[next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != '0'), len(result)):] or ['0']
['5', '0', '1']
>>> result = ['0','0','5','0','1']
>>> result[next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != '0'), len(result)):] or ['0']
['5', '0', '1']
>>> result = ['7', '0','0','5','0','1']
>>> result[next((i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x != '0'), len(result)):] or ['0']
['7', '0', '0', '5', '0', '1']
```

**EXPRESSION LOGIC**

The critical clauses are in the deepest part of the comprehension:

```
(i for
    i, x in enumerate(result)
        if x != '0')
```

In the `enumerate` clause, `i, x` iterates through the list indices and its contents: `(0, '0')`, `(1, '5')`, etc.

The `if` checks for zero characters; it filters out all zeroes.  The `i for` part doesn't get any `i` value until the inner clause finds a non-zero.

At *that* point, the outer `next` operator takes over: it takes the first index of a non-zero and returns that to the slice operator (note that colon at the end), which returns the remainder of the list.

As `pault` already mentioned, the `len` at the end is the default value: if your zero filter disqualifies the entire list (all zeroes), then the comprehension returns `len(result)` to `next`.  This mean that `next` will return the list length, and your `result` slicing returns an empty list.  *Now* your **or** expression has a "Falsy" value in the first operand; it returns the second operand, the list `['0']`.